# Bootstrap 3 Filter add class to parent div and highlight value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">

<pre>
   <div id="myDIV">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean </h2><br>


                     Nam quam nunc, blandit vel,


      <div>
      ----------------------------------------------------------------------
         1. DATE: 03/02/19  
      ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            Title    Dummy Text Generator 
            Options : Many different Options here


      Name:                                          Tony Starks

      Category:
         Super Heros                                  



      </div>
      <div>
      ----------------------------------------------------------------------
         1. DATE: 05/12/19  
      ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            Title    Title for number 2   
            Options : Anything here
            Filler: Something Here

      Name:                                          Superman

      Category:
         Testing test                                   Hello


      </div>
      <div>
      ----------------------------------------------------------------------
         2. DATE: 07/24/17  
      ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            Title    Sports
            Options : Baseball
            Filler: More goodies here


      Name:                                          Iron Man

      Category:
         Something Here                 

      </div>
   </div>
</pre>

<script type="text/javascript">
   (function ($) {
       $('#myInput').keyup(function() {
           var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
           console.log(value);
           $("#myDIV *").filter(function() {
               $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
           });
           $(this).parent().closest('div').addClass("results");
       });
   })(jQuery);   
</script>
```

The way this currently works is that when searching/filtering, it adds a display:none to all elements that don't contain the value inputted.

I want to add a class called `results` to the parent div for the values that are found. Since right now it adds a `display:none` to all elements I have, all `<br>` tags inside of the filtered block are not being displayed, losing it's format (Check format in #myDiv).

```
.results * {
    display: block;
}
```

I'm hoping by adding the above CSS, it should keep the elements inside the filtered block from losing it's format.

Also, if I want to highlight the value word that the user selected, how would one recommend approaching this?

Comment: what did you try that did not work? You can ave a look to [mcve] to improve your question.

Comment: ```$(this).parent().addClass("results");``` adds the class results to all divs, I just want it for the divs that have the filtered value in it.

Comment: then you should get the result of your filter statement, and loop over elements to add them the class you want.